# how to obtain the original array out of cacheService using GAS

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

I'm experimenting with the cache.

I noticed if you store an array of strings the strings will be separated by a `komma` .
I couldn't find a method that allows to retrieve the array as an array, only as a string seems possible.
Obviously retrieval of the array by splitting the string obtained will cause a problem if the array elements contain komma's. This can happen if storing titles of books or newspaper articles etc.

```
function test()
{
   var delimiter = '\r\n';

   var xx = '';
   for (var i=0; i<10; i++) xx = xx + '_' + i;

   var numMax = 1024;

   var extra = ',';

   var string = [];
   var total = '';
   for (var i=0; i<numMax; i++)
   {
      string[i] = 'string[' + i + ']=' + i + extra + xx;
      total = total + string[i] + delimiter;
   }  

   total = total.substr(0, total.length - delimiter.length); // Remove the delimiter at the end of the string

   cacheScript.put('test_total', total);
   cacheScript.put('test_string', string);

   var test_total = cacheScript.get('test_total');
   Logger.log('test_total=\n' + test_total);

   var test_string = [];
   test_string = cacheScript.get('test_string'); // Will NOT retrieve an array but a string
   Logger.log('test_string=\n' + test_string); 

   var wrong = test_string.split(',');       // Will NOT retrieve the original array

   var right = test_total.split(delimiter);  // Will reproduce the original array
}
```

So I would like to know if data stored using cacheService can be restored into the original array without adding a delimiter myself (like in 'total') or splitting on komma (like in 'test_string')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `join(delimiter)` and `split(delimiter)` with any character that will never be present in any "normal" string.

I usually use something like `|` or `∏` like in the example below

```
var array = ['any string,really any','test-any-chrs','56'];
var string = array.join('∏');
var recovered = string.split('∏');
Logger.log('array = '+array+'  length = '+array.length);
Logger.log('string = '+string);
Logger.log('recovered = '+recovered+'  length = '+ recovered.length);
```

[image]

note also that if you want to be more *serious* there is a JavaScript method for that : [JSON.stringify(object)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) and [JSON.parse(string)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: Do not manually parse it. It will break in Many cases. Just use json parse

Comment: OK. I couldn't get JSON to recreate the string[] array. I also wonder what happens if character ' will be used in the texts  (a number of [dutch] words use that character). Basically Serge indicated a delimiter has to be chosen and a string needs to be created and split, in fact what I did.